# Convert Dictionary to CSV Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that's in the following format:

```
mydict = {'item1': ['label1_item', 'label2_item', 'label3_item', 'label4_item'], ...
        'item999': ['label1_item999', 'label2_item999', 'label3_item999', 'label4_item999']}
```

this is how i'm currently outputing the dictionary:

```
filename = datetime.now().strftime('output_-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

df.to_csv(filename,encoding='utf-8', header = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'], sep=',')
```

I want to label the first column "item", but I am unable to label the first column, I have labels for columns 2 (label1)- columns 5 (label4). How do I modify my script to do so?

Comment: How is `df` related to `mydict`? What is `filenstrong textame`? Please include a complete minimal example.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: The code that you posted cannot be executed. You have only two columns ('item' and 'item999') but four headers ('label1', .., 'label4'). It is not possible to understand what you want without having a _working_ minimal example. Please update your question.

Comment: I have a dictionary that has 999 keys, each of the keys fall under the column called item. Each key has 4 values assigned to it, these will be additional columns 2 -5. For example, for the key labeled as item1, this will be the first row under column 1, and its 4 values will go in columns 2-5. Item999 will be the 999th row, I wanted the item999 name under the item column (sort of like a primary key) and its values will go in the columns 2-5 in row 999. Hopefully this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you want, so I am assuming you want rows to be labeled ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'] and columns to be labeled ['item', 'item99']

Reset index:

```
df.index = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4']
```

Save:

```
df.to_csv(filename,encoding='utf-8', sep=',', header=['item', 'item99'])
```

> **Edit:**

Based on your comment:
your dataframe needs to be transposed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict).T
```

which yields:

```
                      0               1               2               3
item1       label1_item     label2_item     label3_item     label4_item
item999  label1_item999  label2_item999  label3_item999  label4_item999
```

then save:

```
df.to_csv(filename,encoding='utf-8', header=['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'], sep=',')
```

Comment: I want the columns to be labeled item, label1, label2, label3, label4 and I will have 999 rows ( a 999 by 5 matrix)